# How to load environment specific configurations and properties with Spring boot using Maven Profiles and Settings Example

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Read the mongodb user name and password from settings.xml based on profile selection in pom.xml. 
I am not getting idea how to do. Can any one give example.

I followed reference link

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/loading-environment-specific-configurations-properties-spring-using-maven-profiles-xml-settings-file-example/

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">//here showing error


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Spring Maven Properties Example Code</name>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <resource.directory>src/main/resources</resource.directory>

</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>

</parent>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test Artifacts -->


</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <!-- Dev Env. Properties -->
        <properties>
            <profile.name>${profile.name}</profile.name>
            <!-- Database Properties -->
            <db.driverClass>${db.driverClass}</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>${db.connectionURL}</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>${db.username}</db.username>
            <db.password>${db.password}</db.password>

        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <!-- Test Env. Properties -->
        <properties>
            <profile.name>${profile.name}</profile.name>
            <!-- Database Properties -->
            <db.driverClass>${db.driverClass}</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>${db.connectionURL}</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>${db.username}</db.username>
            <db.password>${db.password}</db.password>

        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <!-- Prod Env. Properties -->
        <properties>
            <profile.name>${profile.name}</profile.name>
            <!-- Database Properties -->
            <db.driverClass>${db.driverClass}</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>${db.connectionURL}</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>${db.username}</db.username>
            <db.password>${db.password}</db.password>

        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <!-- Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured 
            resource directories are replaced with the property values found from the 
            profile specific configuration file. -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${resource.directory}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>
```

application.properites

```
db.connectionURL=${db.connectionURL}
db.username=${db.username}
db.password=${db.password}
```

I put the settings.xml file in current project dir.
settings.xml

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <!-- Dev Env. Properties -->
            <properties>
                <profile.name>dev</profile.name>
                <!-- Database Properties -->
                <db.driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClass>
<db.connectionURL>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb</db.connectionURL>
<db.username>postgres</db.username>
<db.password>postgres</db.password>

            </properties>
        </profile>
        </profiles>
```

MainApplication

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here i am testing for postgres weather it is working or not but showing error in pom.xml file here

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

the error is

```
Project build error: 
Resolving expression: '${db.password}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'db.password': [db.password]
```

I want to test scenarios for postgres and monngodb.

Help me out..

Comment: I'm not sure we can give you a more explicit example than the one you linked to. Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: @RemyG while i am doing same example provided in above link by using spring boot . Its showing in pom.xml  like  Project build error: Resolving expression: '${db.connectionURL}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'db.connectionURL': [db.connectionURL]

Comment: Demonstrate your source code please.

Comment: If you are using spring boot use spring boot profiles but **NOT** maven profiles..

Comment: Updated source code, could you give me suggestion  weather it is worked or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, the syntax for Maven filtering is slightly different. You should use `@propery@` instead of `${property}`. So you should change your application.properties as follows :

```
db.connectionURL=@db.connectionURL@
db.username=@db.username@
db.password=@db.password@
```

[This blog](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/maven-resource-filtering.html) gives more details

Comment: so far I explored  If I use above blog for defining properties in pom.xml like  <properties> <db.username>username</db.username>
    </properties> , In later point of time someone changed username so again i have to do update  username in pom.xml and build it again. If i use settings.xml file there is no need of changing any pom file.

Comment: You are right, if you set properties in settings.xml, you don't have to change pom.xml. However, my suggestion is just to modify your application.properties in order to follow Spring Boot syntax. I think it's all you have to do.